# Rails Admin select/multiselects - choose searchable_columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

For select/multiselects fields:

It seems the searches are on all columns by default.. I tried below, but it still searches in all columns

```
     field :user do 
       searchable_columns "email"
     end
```

I also tried

```
     searchable [{User => :email}]
```

...and lots of other things.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was digging around in the `searchable` code tonight and found several examples in the spec in [base_spec.rb](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/spec/rails_admin/config/fields/base_spec.rb). Try this:

```
field :user do
  searchable :name
end
```

There is easier-to-read documentation in the wiki under [List](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List) – which explains the same syntax.

Comment: Its for a form (edit do ... end). Maybe I didnt make that clear enough.

Comment: This works for the list context.  Not for the edit or any other context involving a single record.